# Is it possible to change light setups in Blender after render? (Like switch day/night/lamps etc)

Tags: compositing-nodes, light

Sorry for my english. Is it possible to make things like on attached image in Blender compositor?[image: Image from Pixelary Blog]

Picture from Pixelary blog.

I have tried hard to find an answer by myself for 2 weeks and i failed, tried to ask Mike from Pixelary but he did not respond, tried to render different light sourses on different layers and then edit Defuse/Glossy direct/indirect passes and emission but in all cases I got terrible results.

Comment: It is possible with Lux render, awesome feature. You can alter the strength and the temperature in post!

Comment: Thank you for your response, i can do it in corona, but sorry i forgot to mention i need to do it in Cycles. 

I dont know english good enough to explain why :D
But i got a bunch of reasons to do it that way.

Comment: You could duplicate the original .blend and give the duplicate .blend files names like "room_001" room_2" et. make changes  and render separately. OR you could duplicate the room and move it to a different layer. Make you changes and render each layer. *** If your  object properties are "Linked" this would not work.